# How to show $U(n)$ is a group?

Tags: group-theory, matrices

The first part of the question is the following:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be complex $n \times n$ matrices. If $A = (a_{ij})$ then we define its complex conjugate as $\overline{A} = (\overline{a_{ij}})$ . Show that $$\overline{A + B} = \overline A + \overline B,$$ $$\overline{AB} = \overline A \times \overline B.$$

The second part of the questions is:

> Show that $U(n)$ is a group.

I don't see how the second part is related to the first part (don't know if it is in the first place) -- so am I supposed to use the results to the first part in order to answer the second part?

If not, how am I supposed to show $U(n)$ is a group? Do I have to show it for a general binary operation ($*$)? Or for specific ones like addition and multiplication?

If for a general binary operation, how could one do it?

Thank you.

Comment: To specify a group, you must specify a binary operation. Are you using addition or multiplication?

Comment: There is no 'general' binary operation. For specifying a group, you have to specify which operation you are talking about.

Comment: @ncmathsadist that's where I'm confused - I didn't know which binary operation was relevant!

Comment: @nonlinearism thank you!

Comment: @induktio it doesn't bother me and others won't care either but their are some in the camp that what you are doing is a sin against humanity. There is no rule that you can't. I was just letting you know. Keep at it is my thought.

Comment: @dustin Got my Copy Editor gold badge :D Not too bad considering yesterday I was below 2000 rep and had fewer than 250 edits at that point. Cheers to keeping MSE clean and high quality!

Comment: @dustin Yeah it took some work. The hardest thing was actually making sure my edits weren't trivial--it had to really actually correct something; there was a time or two when I "cancelled" because I realized I really didn't have much to add. Quite the adventure. Hey can you chat on MSE? Or how does that work?

Comment: @dustin apparently not? Where would I go to view/see it? I don't see any notification or anything (other than from the comment you just left).

Answer (score 4):

$U(n)$ is defined as the set of all matrices $X$ with the property that $X X^* = I$.

```
Does the group have identity?
```

$I I^* = I$ and $I X = X = XI$ for all $X \in U(n)$

```
Does every element have an inverse in U(n)?
```

Yes, because if $X X^* = I$, then $X^* (X^*)^*= X^* X = I^* = I$ and so the  multiplicative inverse $X^*$ is also in $U(n)$.

```
Is the product of any two elements in the group?
```

Yes, because if $X, Y \in U(n)$, then $(X Y) (X Y)^* = (X Y) (Y^* X^*) = X (Y Y^*) X^* = X I X^* = X X^* = I$

Edit:  Using bars and transposes worked horribly, I will denote $A^*$ as $A$ conjugate transpose

Comment: Try using `\overline{ }` instead of `\bar{ }`.

Answer (score 1):

$U(n)$ is the set of complex $n\times n$ matrices $A$ such that $\overline{(A^T)}=A^{-1}$. This is a group under matrix multiplication, which isn't too difficult to verify. It certainly *can't* be a group under addition, because the zero matrix has no inverse, so can't be in $U(n)$, but both the identity matrix and its additive opposite *are* in $U(n)$, so $U(n)$ isn't closed under matrix addition. While it may well be a group under some other binary operation, they'd probably have given you a definition for said operation before asking you to prove it.